# How can I exclude/ disallow field in Validator in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I have 2 forms

1. Add Book (addBook.jsp) and It's controller (AddBookController.java)
2. Edit Book(editBook.jsp) and It's controller (EditBookController.java)

`Book.java` is bean class for both views.

I have same UI for `editBook.jsp` and `addBook.jsp`.

I have created `org.springframework.validation.Validator` (`BookValidator.java`) for add book same Validator can be use for EditBookController.java

But in `AddBookController` when user is entering Book information user must enter unique bundle number. I have some validations for Unique bundle number on `BookValidator`.

This validations must not work while user EditBook.

I want to exclude / disallow field for validations while book edit.

I have done

```
binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] {"bundleNumber"});
```

but not helped me.

Please suggest me How i can re use validator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need two validators. Perhaps the more specific one can be a subclass of the more general one. The [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) may help here with different, overridable methods for each piece of validation.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have developed according to template method pattern. It helped me a lot.